# Replicate array rows

Tags: python, numpy, array-broadcasting

I want to assign the elements of a 1d array (dimension n) into each row of a 2d array (dimension mxn). Is there a way to use numpy broadcasting to do it in one line?

Comment: Is the mxn already created?

Comment: A [mcve] would reduce the ambiguity of your question.

Comment: Please clarify your question, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`np.broadcast_to`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html). Here's an example:

```
a = np.array([1,3,4,2])

m = 5
np.broadcast_to(a,(m,len(a)))

array([[1, 3, 4, 2],
       [1, 3, 4, 2],
       [1, 3, 4, 2],
       [1, 3, 4, 2],
       [1, 3, 4, 2]])
```

Or another way could be to use `np.vstack`:

```
np.vstack([a]*m)
```